# How to get real resolution in PhoneGap?

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I have seen many such questions where the suggested solution is to use:-

```
window.innerWidth
window.innerHeight
```

However, the webviews scale the screen based on on the devices dpi. So, on devices 1px could be (say) 2 times the actual. So, I am guessing I cannot rely on the above. I am using the following `meta` on my page.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
```

Is there any PhoneGap plugin or anything for this?

Answer (score 0):

Use this :

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, target-densitydpi=medium-dpi, user-scalable=0" />
```

It is the best i've ever encountered. Had the same issue earlier, but this solved my issue.
You can play with the `target-densitydpi` too.